# Show field based on multiple enum values - Odin

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, odin-inspector

I want to Show the field in UnityInspector based on specific enum field.

Lets say this is the enum class

```
  public enum Mode
    {
        None,
        Movement,
        Rotation,
        Scale
    }
```

I want to enable this field if "Movement or Scale" is selected from the enum dropdown, otherwise hide the field.

```
        public Vector3 NewValues;
```

With Odin I can do:

```
    [ShowIf("tweenMode", TweenMode.Movement)]
    public Vector3 NewValues;
```

But that will work only on Movement enum. Any idea on how to make it work on multiple enums? Thanks

Comment: i stumbled over it just yesterday, but i wasnt able to figure it out, i just went back to a string method in my case

Comment: When creating a new tag it's always appreciated if you also add a [guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/odin/info) and preferably, a description.

Comment: Like @GertArnold says, tags without a description are useless. They only lead ti confusion instead of adding more clarity. In this particular case it should also rather have been [`odin-inspector`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/odin-inspector/info) since [`odin`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/odin/info) rather refers to Samsung's firmware flashing Software. I was so free to create both tags and add descriptions and change your tags accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Afaik you can simply do something like

```
private bool showNewValues => tweenMode == TweenMode.Movement || tweenMode == TweenMode.Rotation;

[ShowIf(nameof(showNewValues))]
public Vector3 NewValues;
```

See [`ShowIf`](https://odininspector.com/attributes/show-if-attribute)

Comment: It's not exactly elegant solution but its good enough. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

You can use a property like mentioned before. You can also make use of Odin's [attribute expressions](https://odininspector.com/tutorials/using-attributes/attribute-expressions) which where added in version [2.1.0.0](https://odininspector.com/patch-notes/2-1-0-0)

```cs
[ShowIf("@tweenMode == TweenMode.Movement || tweenMode == TweenMode.Rotation")]
public Vector3 NewValues;
```

If you consider that easier / more readable is up to you, but it's another option.